# How do bombs work in Bit.Trip Core?

Tags: bit-trip-core

It's pretty obvious that bombs clear the screen of beats, but some of the mechanics surrounding bombs are less obvious.

- how many bombs can you have at once?
- do bombed beats count towards your score?
- does a bomb affect your combo chain?